# Powershell script to FTP files to a remote windows server

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been struggling to get a script to work that can FTP a file to a remote windows server and wanted to see if I could get some help. I searched through multpile pages on StackOverflow and Google and have been unsuccessful so far.Below is the code I have

Logic is as follows:

1. Pick up the oldest file with a pattern within a folder
2. Connect to FTP server
3. Copy the file to the remote server
4. Move the file from the in folder to an archive folder

Code seems to be failing where I try to FTP the file to the server - $webclient.UploadFile($uri,$latestfile)

Getting this exception:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
>   At C:\Downloads\powershell\testmove3.ps1:22 char:26
>   +     $webclient.UploadFile <<<< ($uri,$latestfile)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

```
$source = "C:\downloads\"
$destination = "C:\dest\"
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\downloads | Where-Object { $_.name -like "TEST.CSV-PlainText*.txt" }

$latestfile=gci -path $source | Where-Object { $_.name -like "TEST.CSV-PlainText*.txt"} | sort FirstWriteTime | select -last 1

"Oldest File $latestfile"


## Get ftp object
$ftp_client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$user="someuser"
$pass="somepass"
$ftp_address = "ftp://ftp.testserver.com"


## Make uploads
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name)
"Item is $latestfile"
$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$latestfile)
"File uploaded to remote servr"

Move-Item $latestfile.FullName $destination
"File $latestfile moved"
```

Comment: Wondering why the negative votes ? I genuinely tried a lot of options myself before posting the question. I thought this forum was to help each other out - its ok if you cant help but dont just downvote without providing a reason. This is disheartening.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this code will need to be debugged in order to determine why it is throwing that exception.  You are in a much better position to do that than anyone else is.  For example, we don't know where `$item.Name` comes from, or if `$uri` and `$latestfile` contain sane values when passed to `UploadFile`, or what your diagnostic code (e.g. `"Item is $latestfile"`) is outputting.  It will be difficult to answer this question without that kind of information.  By the way, in your second pipeline you have `sort FirstWriteTime`, which should be `sort LastWriteTime`.

Comment: Also, both variables you use to construct the argument for `New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name)` do not appear anywhere else in the code you provided.  Prior to that you set a variable called `$ftp_address` (different name).

Comment: Thank you. I will add some debug statements so you can follow the flow. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, would anyone know if I need to download and install any specific cmdlets to be able to enable FTP ?

Comment: No additional assemblies or installs are needed to use the classes in the [`System.Net` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.aspx) like you're doing because that is part of the .NET Framework on which PowerShell is built.  The built-in [`Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) is _close_ to coming in handy, though I believe it can only be used for downloads, not uploads.  Otherwise, you'd need to look into third-party modules, but as far as them being a prerequisite for FTP, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, was on it overnight and happy to report that I got a solution - yeeehaw !!

I have even added a logic to trap an exception and send out an email notification. Hope this helps anyone with their FTP issues using Powershell. At the end, it returns a success or failure code to the calling program.

```
#PowerShell.exe -File "C:\temp\FTP.ps1"

trap [Exception] { 
    $recipient = "recipient@yahoo.com"
        $sender = "sender@yahoo.com"
        $server = "test.mailserver.com"
        $subject =  "FTP Test"
        $body = "Exception Title: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName + "`r`n`r`n" + "Exception Details: " + $_.Exception.Message
        $msg = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $sender, $recipient, $subject, $body
        $client = new-object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $server
        $client.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
        $client.Send($msg)

        exit 1 
        }



    $ftpuser  = "testuser"
    $ftppass =  "testpass"  
    $ftpserver =  "ftp://ftp.testserver.com/" 
    $file =  "C:\temp\one.txt"
    $filenewname = "one.txt"
    $webclient =  New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $ftp =  $ftpserver+$filenewname
    $uri =  New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

    #Error was happening because the method call was attempting to use the HttpProxy on the Server machine. 
    #If the proxy is not set to null explicitly in your code, then you will get error - "An exception occurred during a webclient request"
    $webclient.Proxy = $NULL 

    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpuser,$ftppass)  
    "Uploading $filenewname in $ftpserver"
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri,$file)
    "Uploaded $filenewname in $ftpserver"


return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be used in any live support environment, I like to suggest using a prompt for password:

```
$ftppass = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
```